# Error in SQL Query when adding the string by itself in a loop

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jsp

I was getting lock timeouts when I looped my queries in a Servlet so I decided to create a long query that executes just once.

Here is the code:

```
public void deactivateAccount(String[] userList) {
    DBConnectionFactory myFactory = DBConnectionFactory.getInstance();
    Connection con = myFactory.getConnection();

    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        String combinedQueries = "";


        for (int i =0; i<userList.length;i++) {
            String query = "UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE userID = ? ; ";
            combinedQueries += query;
        }

        System.out.println(combinedQueries);

        PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(combinedQueries);

        for (int i =0; i<userList.length;i++) {
            int currentNum = i+1;
            p.setInt(currentNum, Integer.parseInt(userList[i]));

            System.out.println("current num is " + currentNum);
            System.out.println("userlist value is " + Integer.parseInt(userList[i]));

        }


            p.execute();



    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        try {
            con.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
        Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This code is in my DAO - what it does is it loops the string as many times as needed (How many checkboxes the user checks) and then prepares the statement in another loop (Sets the parameters for the prepared statement) and then executes it.

I get the error:

> Severe:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE userID = 1; UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE ' at line 1
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

but when I print the query in the code before executing this is what appears:

> Info:   UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE userID = ?; UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE userID = ?; UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE userID = ?; UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE userID = ?;
>   (assuming 4 checkboxes were clicked)

The method accepts an array that I get from a request.getParameterValues from the servlet.

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best practice to run `PreparedStatement` `execute()` individually for bulk updates (for performance reasons), rather, you need to use `executeBatch()` as shown below:

```
public void deactivateAccount(String[] userList) {

    DBConnectionFactory myFactory = DBConnectionFactory.getInstance();
    Connection con = myFactory.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement p = null;

    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        String query = "UPDATE users SET active='0' WHERE userID = ?";
        p = con.prepareStatement(query);

        for (int i =0; i<userList.length;i++) {
            p.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(userList[i]));
            p.addBatch();
        }
        int[] affectedRecords = p.executeBatch();
        con.commit();
        //you can validate rows before commit, upto your requirement
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        try {
            con.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
        Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
            if(p != null)
              p.close();
            if(con != null)
              con.close();
    }
}
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oraperf.htm) for more details on batch JDBC operations.